# Automate the Android application like puppeteer automates Web application

Tags: android

Is there a framework that will let me automate Android application (for example running in VM) like puppeteer is automating web application?

I would like to periodically create some actions: login, read data, etc.

Any hints are appreciated!
Regards,
Piotr

Comment: Check out Robo Script tests: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-ux-test?hl=en

It is also possible to run them locally.

Comment: thanks, will look into that